# ORM Self-referenced entity not persisting into database properly

Tags: database, orm, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

ive been trying to figure this out for 2 hours now and i cant seem to understand what went wrong.

I am using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

I created a User entity which extends FOSUserBundle's BaseUser class. Within this User entity, i have 3 variables, id, my_mentors and my_mentees. More details are below:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;                

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="my_mentees")
 */
protected $my_mentors;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="my_mentors")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mentor_and_mentee_relationship",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mentors_or_mentees_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $my_mentees;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->my_mentors = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->my_mentees = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getUsername();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}    

/**
 * Add my_mentors
 *
 * @param Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentors
 */
public function addUser(\Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentors)
{
    $this->my_mentors[] = $myMentors;
}

/**
 * Get my_mentors
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getMyMentors()
{
    return $this->my_mentors;
}

/**
 * Get my_mentees
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getMyMentees()
{
    return $this->my_mentees;
}
}
```

I created the self reference because a Mentee(which is a User) will subscribe to a Mentor(which is also a User). I tried to do this using the following function:

```
public function subscribeAction($menteeID, $mentorID)
{                
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();

    $mentor = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:User')
                ->find($mentorID);
    $mentee = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:User')
                ->find($menteeID);                

    $currentMentors = $mentee->getMyMentors();
    if ($currentMentors->contains($mentor))
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('subscribe-notice', 'You have already signed up to this mentor!');
    else
    {
        $mentee->setIsMentor(false);
        $mentee->addUser($mentor);
        $mentor->addUser($mentee);
        $em->persist($mentee);
        $em->persist($mentor);
        $em->flush();            
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('subscribe-notice', 'Subscription succesful!');
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('TestBundle_testpage', array('id' => $mentor->getMentorProfile()->getId()) ));
}
```

The problem here is that when i check the database, it does not persist the data. The mentor-mentee relationship information is not stored in the table "mentor_and_mentee_relationship" as declared by the annotation.

I persisted both $mentor and $mentee in an attempt to get it to work, but apparently it doesnt.

Could my ORM annotation be declared wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same function (addUser) to add a mentor and to add a mentee. This is wrong. First you need two different setters in your entity (I changed the name of addUser to make it clear)

```
/**
 * Add my_mentors
 *
 * @param Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentors
 */
public function addMentor(\Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentors)
{
    $this->my_mentors[] = $myMentors;
}

/**
 * Add my_mentees
 *
 * @param Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentees
 */
public function addMentee(\Fitness\FitBundle\Entity\User $myMentees)
{
    $this->my_mentees[] = $myMentees;
}
```

Then in your controller do:

```
        $mentee->addMentor($mentor);
        $mentor->addMentee($mentee);
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos for your answer. I didnt suspect the addUser() function because it was generated by symfony for me via the doctrine:generate:entities command.

After reading your answer, i made the necessary changes and the data seem to appear in the table. However, there was an issue retrieving the information. Whenever i try to use getMyMentors() or getMyMentees(), doctrine will always return me an empty array collection. This baffled me for another 2 hours.

Comment: Fortunately i managed to solve the problem which may come in handy for others.

The pointer here is modify and persist the inversing side first before modifying and persisting the owning side. See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

A simple example is between a Blog and Comment entity. A blog can have many comments but a comment belong to only 1 blog. So this is a OneToMany relationship (Blog-Comment). In this case, its pretty clear that the blog is the owning side and comment is the inverse side. Hence mod and persist comments first before blog.